# How do i write MySQL queries for find unique people in my user data set?

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have to write MySQL query in the yii2 framework to find out from the user table the same First Name same Last Name along with same Date of Birth or Date of Birth Null.

E.g The list of data I need to retrieve.

```
  FirstName lastName dob
1 Jonny     Pappa    1983-11-03
2 Jonny     Pappa    1983-11-03
3 Jonny     Pappa    NULL
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: typically, a SQL query would start with SELECT and include a FROM clause. We can execute raw SQL from Yii2 framework with `->createCommand("SELECT ... )` and then do a `->queryAll`...  Is this resultset supposed to include all names from the `user` table, or only rows where there is at least one other matching row? Was there a question here, or were we just posting a status report?

Answer (score 0):

We can execute raw SQL SELECT statement with `createCommand` and `queryAll` e.g.

```
  $db = Yii::$app->getDb();
  $command = $db->createCommand($sql);
  $result = $command->queryAll();
```

Assuming we have a primary key, or unique key, that can distinguish rows, we can use SQL like this to identify rows that have at least one other "matching" row.

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.firstname 
      , t,lastname
      , t.dob
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM mytable m
                  WHERE m.firstname <=> t.firstname
                    AND m.lastname  <=> t.lastname
                    AND ( m.dob = t.dob
                        OR m.dob IS NULL
                        OR t.dob IS NULL 
                        )
                    AND m.id <> t.id
               )
  ORDER
     BY t.firstname 
      , t,lastname
      , t.dob
      , t.id
```

The conditions in the subquery are are going to depend on the criteria for matching. The example shown here will cause a row with NULL dob to match a row with same firstname and lastname.

we would expect that statement to return a resultset like this:

```
id  firstname  lastname  dob
--  ---------  --------  ----------
 1  Jonny      Pappa     1983-11-03
 2  Jonny      Pappa     1983-11-03
 3  Jonny      Pappa     NULL
```

if appropriate rows appear in the table.

There are other possible interpretations of the rather vague specification. The requirements could much better be explained with example data and sample output;(We are going to have to have test cases setup for testing anyway.)

---

**EDIT**

There several possible interpretations of the specification "*same Date of Birth or Date of Birth Null*".  The example query provided in this answer satisfies one particular interpretation.

As mentioned previously, providing example data and sample output would go a long ways towards explaining/clarifying the requirements.

Consider sample data like this

```
fn  ln  dob
--  --  ----------
 a   a  NULL

 b   b  1981-11-11

 c   c  1982-12-12
 c   c  1982-12-12

 d   d  NULL
 d   d  1983-03-03
 d   d  1983-03-03

 e   e  NULL
 e   e  NULL
 e   e  1984-04-04
 e   e  1984-04-04

 f   f  NULL
 f   f  1977-07-07
 f   f  1977-07-07
 f   f  1988-08-08

 g   g  NULL
 g   g  NULL
 g   g  1988-08-08
 g   g  1989-09-09
```

What resultset do we expect to be returned? Without a specification, we can write  a wide variety of SQL statements that will return a wide variety of results. And we are going to need to setup test cases, so why not use those same test cases to illustrate the specification.

Otherwise, we are just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The answer is somehow brought me into a stage. But there are some more issues I am facing.

Comment: The answer posted here attempted to answer the question that was asked (was there a question asked?) ... how  to run raw SQL from the Yii2 framework to return a resultset, and to give a demonstration query that would return the expected resultset shown in the question.  If we need a more precise answer to a different (or more specific) question, we can add details and give a more precise specification, including sample data and expected output. Or we are just going to continue guessing what the question is.